# getting error login with lb-service angular StrongLoop SDK

Tags: angularjs, authentication, strongloop

I follow this tutorial to create login using StrongLoop:
http://docs.strongloop.com/display/DOC/AngularJS+JavaScript+SDK

Somehow I get this kind of error message on console browser:

```
TypeError: Object function Resource(value){
        shallowClearAndCopy(value || {}, this);
      } has no method 'login'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is login method for user model? Or by another model like customer/agent? So, if you want to use login method on customer/agent model you must use model extend user. http://docs.strongloop.com/display/LB/Model+definition+reference#Modeldefinitionreference-Extendingamodel

Answer (score 1):

Can you confirm you have generated a lb-services.js file that contains a User factory with the login method?

You should see something like the following:

```
    "login": {
      url: urlBase + "/users/login",
      method: "POST",
      interceptor: {
        response: function(response) {
          var accessToken = response.data;
          LoopBackAuth.currentUserId = accessToken.userId;
          LoopBackAuth.accessTokenId = accessToken.id;
          LoopBackAuth.rememberMe = response.config.params.rememberMe !== false;
          LoopBackAuth.save();
          return response.resource;
        }
      }
    },
```

Can you confirm that?  If you see this code is in the lb-services file then you should check and confirm you are includinging it in your app correctly.

Comment: yes, i got the generated file lb-services under scripts/services directory and that code is around line 80. i call that method on main.js. still get same error message.

Comment: Are you still seeing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be, that you have no User model.

Also, can you provide 2 pieces of code? the code, which calls login() and the code from lb-services.js, which describes it